# Foreach loop, using key identifers in one single array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am using key identifers in my foreach loop in order to control how I echo strings next to the data. For example

The array

```
  $array = array("name" => "Jim", "age" => 34);

array(2) {
  ["name"]=> string(3) "Jim"
  ["age"]=>  int(34)
}
```

The loop

```
<?php
 foreach ($array as $value) {

  echo "Name " .$value["name"]."</br>
    Age ".$value["age"] . "</br>";

 }
?>
```

The output I get

```
Name J
Age J
Name
Age
```

The desired result

```
Name Jim 
Age 34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `foreach` functionality? If you remove that you will get exactly what you want. And you will change `$value` to `$array`.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the foreach loop:

```
echo "Name " . $array["name"] . "</br>\n"
   . "Age "  . $array["age"]  . "</br>\n";
```

Or, if you want to loop over multiple people, you need to make a nested array of arrays.

```
$people = array(
    array("name" => "Jim", "age" => 34),
    array("name" => "Bob", "age" => 42)
);

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo "Name " . $person["name"] . "</br>\n"
       . "Age "  . $person["age"]  . "</br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo ucfirst($key).' '.$value.'<br />';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without a for loop...

```
<?php

  $array = array("name" => "Jim", "age" => 34);
  echo "Name " .$array["name"]."</br>
    Age ".$array["age"]. "</br>";

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a foreach loop for what you're trying to accomplish, it would be as simple as:

```
$array = array("name" => "Jim", "age" => 34);

echo "Name " . $array["name"] . "</br>";
echo "Age " . $array["age"];
```